# How remove residual lines after merge two regions using Geopandas in python?

Tags: python, geopandas, shapefile

```
import geopandas as gpd

sg = gpd.read_file('shapefile1.shp')
sd = gpd.read_file('shapefile2.shp')

kw = sg[sg['region_name'] == 'region1']
tg = sd[sd['region_name'] == 'region2']
```

region1 and region2 are as below:
[image]

```
mr = kw.geometry.reset_index(drop=True).union(tg.geometry.reset_index(drop=True))
mr.plot()
```

I can get the image from mr as below:

[image]

But, see the boundary of the region

```
mr.boundary.plot()
```

[image]

I can see the residual lines as the image above.

How remove these residual lines?

I'v tried to remove them using simplify(tolerance=0.01) and buffer(0) functions.
But I failed.

I just expect to get outlines of the first image with empty inside.

Comment: A wild guess, those "residual lines" are not lines, but the holes of the combined polygon. If I am correct, you just delete the holes in it.

Comment: @swatchai How can I distinguish those holes? I tried to remove them by coordinations, but it is very hard work....

Comment: I solve it myself with mr=mr.apply(lambda geom: geom.exterior).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the benefits of the readers, I offer this answer that shows the relevant steps including runnable code that is missing in the question.

```
import os
os.environ['USE_PYGEOS'] = '0'
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

# Create 2 geodataframes each containing a simple polygon 
polygon_geom1 = Polygon(zip([0, 1.05, 1.05, 0], [-0.1, -0.1, 1.2, 1.2]))
#crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}
crs = 'epsg:4326'
polygon1 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(index=[0], crs=crs, geometry=[polygon_geom1])

polygon_geom2 = Polygon(zip([0+1, 1+1, 1+1, 0+1, 0.1+1, 0+1], [0,0,1,1,0.5,0]))
polygon2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(index=[0], crs=crs, geometry=[polygon_geom2])

# Plot to see them together
ax1 = polygon1.plot(ec='k', color='y')
polygon2.plot(ax=ax1, ec='r', color='lightgray', alpha=0.8)
```

[image: union-of-2]

Next, we do the union of the two geometries:-

```
polygon1.geometry.values[0].union(polygon2.geometry.values[0])
```

then, the exterior geometry:-

```
polygon1.geometry.values[0].union(polygon2.geometry.values[0]).exterior
```

and, finally, the interior geometry:-

```
# The interiors of the unioned geometry
# This show item 0 of them
polygon1.geometry.values[0].union(polygon2.geometry.values[0]).interiors[0]
```

[image: in-and-ex-geoms]

**Part 2**

This is another example with modified input geometries that will create 2 holes when perform "union" operation.

The code below will show how to create a union-polygon that keeps the large hole in it.

```
import os
os.environ['USE_PYGEOS'] = '0'
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

# Create 2 geodataframes each containing a simple polygon 
polygon_geom1 = Polygon(zip([0, 1.05, 1.05, 0], [-0.1, -0.1, 1.2, 1.2]))
#crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}
crs = 'epsg:4326'
polygon1 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(index=[0], crs=crs, geometry=[polygon_geom1])

polygon_geom2 = Polygon(zip([1, 2, 2, 1, 
                         1.1, 0.95, 1.2 ,
                         1], 
                        [0,0,1,1,
                         0.8,0.7,0.4,
                         0]))
polygon2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(index=[0], crs=crs, geometry=[polygon_geom2])

# Plot to see them together
ax1 = polygon1.plot(ec='k', color='y')
polygon2.plot(ax=ax1, ec='r', color='lightgray', alpha=0.7)
```

[image: unionof2]

```
# The union of the two geometries
# There are 2 holes in it
union_poly = polygon1.geometry.values[0].union(polygon2.geometry.values[0])
union_poly

# The exterior of the unioned geometry
ext_poly = polygon1.geometry.values[0].union(polygon2.geometry.values[0]).exterior
ext_poly

# The interiors of the unioned geometry
# This shows item 0 of them
int_poly0 =  polygon1.geometry.values[0].union(polygon2.geometry.values[0]).interiors[0]
int_poly0

# The polygon that contain the big hole only
# (small hole is excluded)
diff_poly = Polygon(ext_poly).difference(Polygon(int_poly0))
diff_poly
```

[image: union1and2]

[image: keepbighole]

Comment: Thank you. '.interiors' are also useful for some cases. Great!

Answer (score 1):

The Typical way I deal with this is to use [shapely.set_precision](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/shapely.set_precision.html). This will round the coordinates to the precision specified and, more importantly for this case, will remove polygons narrower than it as well.

The advantage is that it will only remove slivers (narrow polygons) rather than all islands, which can be a problem if there is an island in the polygon you want to retain.

Runnable code snippet:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import shapely

regions_str = """{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
    "features": [
        { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "OBJECTID": 15, "CTYUA21CD": "E06000015", "CTYUA21NM": "Derby", "CTYUA21NMW": " ", "BNG_E": 435609, "BNG_N": 335375, "LONG": -1.47189, "LAT": 52.9146, "GlobalID": "{1EE723F8-3573-4015-94E5-309FF5470969}", "SHAPE_Length": 0.48686017434828832, "SHAPE_Area": 0.010462188225935753 }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ -1.388263158999962, 52.901468313000066 ], [ -1.383074406999924, 52.925931570000046 ], [ -1.423964123999951, 52.935651069000073 ], [ -1.409280628999966, 52.950322644000039 ], [ -1.468552191999947, 52.950662306000027 ], [ -1.474630539999964, 52.965928030000043 ], [ -1.495405481999967, 52.965879363000056 ], [ -1.508028820999925, 52.937451810000027 ], [ -1.544068498999934, 52.924207739000053 ], [ -1.556852229999947, 52.914678774000038 ], [ -1.541691004999961, 52.889539927000044 ], [ -1.503112225999928, 52.884845448000078 ], [ -1.494512787999952, 52.870078996000075 ], [ -1.464086400999975, 52.872559915000068 ], [ -1.446226830999933, 52.861309424000069 ], [ -1.42356744999995, 52.865078049000033 ], [ -1.418912588999945, 52.884546472000068 ], [ -1.402772273999972, 52.900462453000046 ], [ -1.388263158999962, 52.901468313000066 ] ] ] ] } },
        { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "OBJECTID": 131, "CTYUA21CD": "E10000007", "CTYUA21NM": "Derbyshire", "CTYUA21NMW": " ", "BNG_E": 426752, "BNG_N": 353556, "LONG": -1.6021, "LAT": 53.078602, "GlobalID": "{50013D4D-5E3F-41A5-AA1A-9E510EC6F4DE}", "SHAPE_Length": 4.4373405951410634, "SHAPE_Area": 0.34262300924593908 }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ -1.873492625999972, 53.540429652000057 ], [ -1.894109491999927, 53.533611779000069 ], [ -1.909620831999973, 53.538390987000071 ], [ -1.926780655999949, 53.520948751000049 ], [ -1.92197284599996, 53.509954685000082 ], [ -1.951332674999946, 53.504198840000072 ], [ -1.96338598899996, 53.509827262000044 ], [ -1.987819574999946, 53.481110400000034 ], [ -1.985792377999928, 53.455226773000049 ], [ -2.008234852999976, 53.441549300000077 ], [ -2.004216051999947, 53.435921786000051 ], [ -2.014227504999951, 53.439762755000061 ], [ -2.026255417999948, 53.429865162000056 ], [ -2.01369718199993, 53.415890111000067 ], [ -1.992329470999948, 53.415193133000059 ], [ -2.004642866999973, 53.386327278000067 ], [ -2.03377543299996, 53.375541570000053 ], [ -2.031058462999965, 53.370262387000082 ], [ -2.006785051999941, 53.354572113000074 ], [ -2.009481850999975, 53.260652456000059 ], [ -1.974858753999968, 53.231061053000076 ], [ -1.990264535999927, 53.22299890000005 ], [ -1.98740775899995, 53.213585849000026 ], [ -1.962364609999952, 53.226241737000066 ], [ -1.95670722999995, 53.213747610000041 ], [ -1.898632930999952, 53.199956980000081 ], [ -1.860731528999963, 53.188425566000035 ], [ -1.81254008999997, 53.154343116000064 ], [ -1.821876370999973, 53.136704070000064 ], [ -1.783725895999964, 53.102827982000065 ], [ -1.794239019999964, 53.088394058000063 ], [ -1.77565273099998, 53.059354643000063 ], [ -1.778981296999973, 53.044844375000082 ], [ -1.758931441999948, 53.037315774000035 ], [ -1.762404687999947, 52.999857683000073 ], [ -1.826780964999955, 52.97708576000008 ], [ -1.829799316999924, 52.945705986000064 ], [ -1.856575599999928, 52.923390961000052 ], [ -1.828209594999976, 52.884427756000036 ], [ -1.777220650999936, 52.883814741000037 ], [ -1.746003281999947, 52.868693160000078 ], [ -1.725322054999936, 52.859663185000045 ], [ -1.704345049999972, 52.866680593000069 ], [ -1.700608765999959, 52.860583525000038 ], [ -1.690271819999964, 52.864469378000081 ], [ -1.626754563999953, 52.854437175000044 ], [ -1.585352039999975, 52.83171462100006 ], [ -1.610494536999965, 52.816404310000053 ], [ -1.591826859999969, 52.809490592000031 ], [ -1.588870365999981, 52.799865986000043 ], [ -1.614345378999928, 52.788274048000062 ], [ -1.611129501999926, 52.781403561000047 ], [ -1.666536746999952, 52.784723033000034 ], [ -1.704158000999939, 52.732078778000073 ], [ -1.656607726999937, 52.721748474000037 ], [ -1.655041567999945, 52.698798581000062 ], [ -1.597541044999957, 52.70042176700008 ], [ -1.550041252999961, 52.720317020000039 ], [ -1.544640246999961, 52.731694499000071 ], [ -1.562492621999979, 52.750586837000071 ], [ -1.552787043999956, 52.763332953000031 ], [ -1.504980452999973, 52.767608663000033 ], [ -1.493983722999928, 52.759047373000044 ], [ -1.468445303999943, 52.766877352000051 ], [ -1.455882042999974, 52.777094663000071 ], [ -1.462778635999939, 52.786863461000053 ], [ -1.442391054999973, 52.792983277000076 ], [ -1.443561551999949, 52.80274417000004 ], [ -1.417704458999935, 52.801615501000072 ], [ -1.387936183999955, 52.833097656000064 ], [ -1.394322841999951, 52.836772874000076 ], [ -1.361210666999966, 52.855185672000061 ], [ -1.351172739999924, 52.853289454000048 ], [ -1.34486272099997, 52.867532886000049 ], [ -1.325332493999952, 52.865981743000077 ], [ -1.319306874999938, 52.872869429000048 ], [ -1.267889078999929, 52.873368652000067 ], [ -1.240055489999975, 52.880108857000039 ], [ -1.239705992999973, 52.892289237000057 ], [ -1.246215039999925, 52.90298591800007 ], [ -1.281801032999965, 52.910293268000032 ], [ -1.281031119999966, 52.949158338000075 ], [ -1.292501164999976, 52.955573678000064 ], [ -1.287749331999976, 52.969662454000058 ], [ -1.307443724999928, 53.003654790000041 ], [ -1.331986478999966, 53.031145030000062 ], [ -1.33586846299994, 53.052965847000053 ], [ -1.344427658999962, 53.065542545000028 ], [ -1.331635476999963, 53.080987888000038 ], [ -1.302882937999925, 53.088202197000044 ], [ -1.309251408999955, 53.096770175000074 ], [ -1.300618904999965, 53.102049375000036 ], [ -1.321780227999966, 53.130650307000053 ], [ -1.323446840999964, 53.162342453000065 ], [ -1.300711788999934, 53.164214540000046 ], [ -1.295961787999943, 53.171224863000077 ], [ -1.259925338999949, 53.164479444000051 ], [ -1.240445849999958, 53.178650614000048 ], [ -1.196936161999929, 53.184817905000045 ], [ -1.209424481999974, 53.217696765000028 ], [ -1.201996816999952, 53.23555532000006 ], [ -1.21302650299998, 53.247672497000053 ], [ -1.20245028599993, 53.261219543000038 ], [ -1.174689788999956, 53.265164710000079 ], [ -1.181541501999959, 53.270032064000077 ], [ -1.166487540999981, 53.277655368000069 ], [ -1.180117019999955, 53.287134747000039 ], [ -1.17662736699998, 53.305131654000036 ], [ -1.199742828999945, 53.311440185000038 ], [ -1.203239046999954, 53.304223241000045 ], [ -1.230687933999945, 53.308559736000063 ], [ -1.243868382999949, 53.301569792000066 ], [ -1.282011412999964, 53.309462591000056 ], [ -1.29567816399998, 53.31503697200003 ], [ -1.288589026999944, 53.326228056000048 ], [ -1.299023009999928, 53.332511637000039 ], [ -1.32466917499994, 53.328810014000055 ], [ -1.33775105199993, 53.315848052000035 ], [ -1.386738712999943, 53.317632135000053 ], [ -1.386571545999971, 53.334902507000038 ], [ -1.411033906999933, 53.341992493000078 ], [ -1.420866495999974, 53.334567952000043 ], [ -1.441972114999942, 53.337492490000045 ], [ -1.459880278999947, 53.330689369000027 ], [ -1.455223581999974, 53.321869142000082 ], [ -1.467912832999957, 53.317120057000068 ], [ -1.50213193999997, 53.317582077000054 ], [ -1.536768861999974, 53.304748674000052 ], [ -1.561729893999939, 53.306411318000073 ], [ -1.561731044999931, 53.315970893000042 ], [ -1.580533895999963, 53.311738090000063 ], [ -1.584902009999951, 53.321587952000073 ], [ -1.599093278999931, 53.311318200000073 ], [ -1.609201583999948, 53.322663962000036 ], [ -1.625493744999972, 53.316423979000035 ], [ -1.632726986999955, 53.320839214000046 ], [ -1.612303061999967, 53.343218670000056 ], [ -1.590547953999931, 53.345920985000078 ], [ -1.663548539999965, 53.366595166000081 ], [ -1.653817821999951, 53.391910827000061 ], [ -1.704965320999975, 53.405055975000039 ], [ -1.708532232999971, 53.417339474000073 ], [ -1.739761961999932, 53.420987916000058 ], [ -1.745322966999936, 53.462175396000077 ], [ -1.768437340999981, 53.464766933000078 ], [ -1.801470631999962, 53.480991762000031 ], [ -1.796288218999962, 53.503152991000036 ], [ -1.822228780999978, 53.521090923000031 ], [ -1.841820827999925, 53.519908780000037 ], [ -1.873492625999972, 53.540429652000057 ] ], [ [ -1.503112225999928, 52.884845449000068 ], [ -1.541691003999972, 52.889539928000033 ], [ -1.556852229999947, 52.914678774000038 ], [ -1.544068498999934, 52.924207739000053 ], [ -1.508028820999925, 52.937451810000027 ], [ -1.495405481999967, 52.965879364000045 ], [ -1.474630539999964, 52.965928030000043 ], [ -1.468552191999947, 52.950662307000073 ], [ -1.409280628999966, 52.950322644000039 ], [ -1.423964123999951, 52.935651069000073 ], [ -1.383074406999924, 52.925931570000046 ], [ -1.388263158999962, 52.901468313000066 ], [ -1.402772273999972, 52.900462453000046 ], [ -1.418912588999945, 52.884546473000057 ], [ -1.42356744999995, 52.865078050000079 ], [ -1.446226830999933, 52.861309425000059 ], [ -1.464086400999975, 52.872559915000068 ], [ -1.494512787999952, 52.870078997000064 ], [ -1.503112225999928, 52.884845449000068 ] ] ] ] } },
    ]
}
"""

regions = gpd.read_file(regions_str)
kw = regions[regions["CTYUA21NM"] == "Derby"]
tg = regions[regions["CTYUA21NM"] == "Derbyshire"]

mr = kw.geometry.reset_index(drop=True).union(tg.geometry.reset_index(drop=True))
mr.plot(edgecolor="black", aspect="equal")

mr = shapely.set_precision(mr, grid_size=0.000001)
mr.plot(edgecolor="black", aspect="equal")

plt.show()
```

Before set_precision there is a small line (= narrow island) in the middle of the polygon. This narrow polygon is the result of a gap (imperfect snap) between the 2 polygons being unioned:

[image]

After set_precision:

[image]

Comment: Very useful. Before set_precision, running "mr.interiors" will  get a list of 1 LINEARRING item. But a list of zero item after set_precision.